# I am using hostgator and on my style sheet it says an error of import not allowed here

Tags: css, import

on the style-sheet on the side it states an error "@import not allowed here"
and I am not sure how to fix that.

I have also been reading here that it is best to use  when importing a google font instead?

Comment: You need to show the code you created ([reprex]) as I think you have made either of two mistakes 1) the `@import` not inside a `<style>` tag or 2) the `@import` is not the topmost row (which is mandatory) in your `<style>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Hostgator, the hosting you are using for your website and CSS, is blocking the import at-rule.

This means that you have to contact your hosting provider and temporarily avoid using such at-rules.